# rspec failing:expected 1 errors_on,got 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trade_type,:class_name => 'TradeType',:foreign_key => 'trade_type_id'
  belongs_to :restaurant,:class_name => 'Restaurant',:foreign_key => 'restaurant_id'
  validates_presence_of :card_no,:message => '卡号不能为空'
  validates_numericality_of :card_no,:message => '卡号必须是数字'
  validates_length_of :card_no,:is => 16,:message => '卡号必须是16位'
  validates_uniqueness_of :card_no,:message => '卡号不能重复'
end

describe Card do
  it 'is valid with card_no,name'do
     card = Card.new(
         card_no: '1054321239876456',
         name: 'zhangsan',
     )
    expect(card).to be_valid
  end

  it 'is invalid without a card_no' do
    card = Card.new(card_no:nil)
    expect(card).to have(1).errors_on(:card_no)
  end
end
```

Comment: we need more information - like the code for the class this is testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing 3 errors instead of 1 is because `Card.card_no` is blank.  That means it is also not numeric and also not 16 characters long.

i.e. all three of

```
validates_presence_of :card_no,:message => '卡号不能为空'
validates_numericality_of :card_no,:message => '卡号必须是数字'
validates_length_of :card_no,:is => 16,:message => '卡号必须是16位'
```

are failing.

If you want numericality and length_of to only be validated when the card number is present, add `allow_blank: true`.

ie.

```
validates_presence_of :card_no,:message => '卡号不能为空'
validates_numericality_of :card_no, :allow_blank => true, :message => '卡号必须是数字'
validates_length_of :card_no, :is => 16, :allow_blank => true, :message => '卡号必须是16位'
```

Comment: great!thx!i also want to know how to test card_no is numericality,card_no's length is 16,is there is method i can use?

Comment: You can do it the same way, just change the value of `card_no`.  i.e. `card = Card.new(card_no:'abc')` will test non-numeric, `card = Card.new(card_no:'123456789012345')` will test not 16 long etc.

Comment: Further you can also access `card.errors[:card_no]` to check you are getting exactly the correct error for the failure, not just a count of the errors.

Comment: how to accept your answer?and i also want to know how to use card.errors[:card_no]?

Comment: Click on the tick to the left of the answer, below the up and down vote arrows.  It should turn green when you accept it.

Comment: Not vote up, there should be a tick just below the vote arrows - here is the help http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work - it will increase your reputation too.

Comment: And here is a link that should help you with rspec tests - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/model-specs/errors-on.  e.g. `expect(Card.new.errors_on(:card_no)).to include("can't be blank")`

Comment: i am appreciate your help.